# Rich Text Box inconsistant

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I am working with c# WPF. I have some specific templates which are displayed in rich textbox. These templates have some specific words in bracket. I want to select those words in bracket one by one on click of TAB key.  I have written below code with text pointer. But this code is being inconsistent. The index is getting varied system to system.
Is there any other way to highlight the specific text from rich text box or any property I need to set for rich text box?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox   BorderBrush="Black"  MaxHeight="40"  TextChanged="txtPolicyNumber_TextChanged" LostKeyboardFocus="txtPolicyNumber_LostKeyboardFocus"  BorderThickness="1"  Margin="18,2,19,235" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Width="480" Name="txtPolicyNumber"></TextBox>
    <RichTextBox   AcceptsReturn="True"   MaxHeight="200" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"  TextChanged="rtxtMessage_TextChanged" KeyDown="rtxtMessage_KeyDown" Margin="18,48,19,-44" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="rtxtMessage"  Width="480" ></RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by _inconsistent_? Can you provide minimal reproducible example?

Comment: e.g if my template is like following: I am using (Dot)net (technology), on my machine it is selecting " (Dot) " and " (technology) " correctly. But on some other machine it is giving problem on index. Like it is selecting only "  ot )" from " (Dot) ", only "  chnology )" from "  (technology) ".

Comment: OK but still please provide minimal reproducible example - you haven't done that so far. Thanks.